# HPHP HipHop for PHP Compiler

Tags: php

I'm trying to run HPHP for PHP in Ubuntu platform.

I'm following instructions on this link:
https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php

Is there a step by step tutorial on how to run hiphop with my PHP files? In their documentation, it says run hphp under hphp folder but the file does not exist?

OK, I've got 55.18 (both incl and self) from file_get_contents (called 0) and 43.78 (both incl and self) from curl_exec (called 22 times). I see that there are a minor difference between cURL and file_get_contents. Should I change all of them to cURL? Would that make any difference?

If this is not the issue then, should I look at this issue as server or remote server related?

Comment: Why would you want to run hip hop? How many million users do you have per day?

Comment: Well my script uses too much of server memory and it is run approximately 30 minutes every run. It's built in PHP. I was thinking of transforming to lower level language like C++ would be helpful in terms of performance.

Comment: It's more likely your script just needs optimization. You'll create more headaches by using Hiphop, it makes deployment a fair bit harder.

Comment: I have already optimized by using best practices such as taking out unnecessary calculations outside the loops, using array_push instead of .= concatenation, using cURL instead of file_get_contents just to name a few

Comment: Unfortunately hiphop is not pixie dust and it will not improve the performance from 30 minutes to 5 seconds. Try to find what exactly takes 30 minutes to perform with profiler

Comment: @Jae: what you have enumerated *is not* optimizations. It is how code should be written.

Comment: @zerkms, should I use Xdebug?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: @Jae: before **any** optimization steps you need to use any profiler you are familiar with. Like xdebug, yes. After you've found the bottleneck - improve that piece of code. And check the performance once again. If it is not still good enough - find next bottleneck. Repeat until timers are not well.

Comment: For profiling you can use xdebug + cachegrind or xhprof for example. Next to that there are more tools, see http://derickrethans.nl/talks.html there are some profiling slides. If you can visit one of his talks. And there is http://about.digg.com/blog/rasmus-lerdorf-php-performance which is also about HPHP.

Comment: Use xhprof, it's much easier to base conclusions of, than cachegrind.

Answer (score 1):

> Ubuntu version 11.04

You find the installation instructions (step by step) here: [Building and installing on Ubuntu 11.04](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Building-and-Installing-on-Ubuntu-11.04).

More general information is available in the [hiphop-php wiki](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki).